# vagrant doesn't boot up

Tags: window, vagrant

I'm trying to boot up my VM using the 'vagrant up' command but with no success.it get some error like following:

```
vagrant destroy&&vagrant up
    default: Are you sure you want to destroy the 'default' VM? [y/N] y
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu1404'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: ubuntu_default_1427785207620_64334
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
    default: Adapter 3: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
```

I have tried some method form here:https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-doesnt-boot-up

my software information:

vagrant 1.7.2
virtualbox  4.3.26
window 8.1

anyone have idea to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems its a virtual box / vagrant version incompatibility issue

I uninstalled Virtual Box 4.3.14 and installed Virtual Box 4.3.12 and it worked. Basically I downgraded virtual box.

I found the answer here [Vagrant Connection Refused Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346093/vagrant-connection-refused-error)